# writing python code to execute command in main terminal however i need to include ' ' and its not workig

Tags: python, terminal

I am writing a piece of code and in the middle of it I want it to go into the main terminal and strip my data set of [] and '' however when i include the '' part python thinks i'm just finishing the string (i think) is there another way I can do this. Here is my code:

```
com=['cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]''*//g" >meantenbri.txt']
s0=''
com=s0.join(com)
res=os.system(com)
```

python does not recognize that I want the whole line to be executed in the terminal , in particular the '' in the middle section.

Comment: You probably don't want to fork out to the shell and several other subprocesses to remove a few characters from a file.  It would be a lot easier to do this right in Python code.

Comment: I agree 100% with Sven, and, FWIW, I'm willing to bet that this is a `UUOC` (useless use of cat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]''*//g" >meantenbri.txt2'` is not doing what you think it is, for example:

```py
>>> print 'cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]''*//g" >meantenbri.txt2'
cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]*//g" >meantenbri.txt2
```

Note that those two single quotes in the middle are gone, this is happening because you actually have two separate strings side by side, `'cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]'` and
`'*//g" >meantenbri.txt2'`, and the interpreter concatenates these strings together.  To actually include those single quotes in the string, there are a couple of options:

- Use triple quoting:

```py
    com = """cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]''*//g" >meantenbri.txt2"""
```

- Escape the single quotes in the middle:

  ```
  com = 'cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]\'\'*//g" >meantenbri.txt2'
  ```

Note that the whole `com = [...]`, `s0 = ''`, `com = ''.join(com)` is really unnecessary, just create `com` as a string from the beginning by removing the square brackets.

As a side note, [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is preferred over `os.system()` for running external programs.  I think in this case it would look something like this (untested):

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['tr', '-d', "s/,[]''*//g"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=open('new.txt'),
                     stdout=open('meantenbri.txt2', 'w'))
p.communicate()
res = p.returncode
```

Although as mentioned by Sven in comments this is not something you should be using an external program for in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Use a triple quoted string instead:

```py
com = ["""cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]''*//g" >meantenbri.txt"""]
```

python actually has 4 types of quotes at your disposal:

```
'...'
"...:
"""..."""
'''...'''
```

(the triple quoted variety also work over multiple lines):

```
"""foo
bar"""
```

Of course, if you're really in a pinch, you can escape quotes with a backslash -- But with so many different types of quotes at your disposal it seems like it should rarely be necessary.

Comment: The parameter to `-d` is a set, so two single quotes in that set don't make any sense.  And I doubt the command is doing what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: good solution(+1) ... but really he should also know about escapes:P

Comment: thanks, yeah i just didn't know about the whole multiple quotes thing. its working perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

```
com=['cat new.txt | tr -d "s/,[]\'\'*//g" >meantenbri.txt2']
```

escape them with \